# Does ecryptfs (perhaps implicitly) checksum data?

Tags: ecryptfs

I am planning to set up a NAS with ecryptfs used for encryption. I am wondering if ecryptfs will tell me if a file has been silently corrupted (by e.g., a faulty harddrive), or if I would still be dependent on the underlying filesystem to do data checksumming for me?

I may use btrfs as the underlying filesystem anyway to get the snapshot feature, but I would still be interested to know if for example ext4 + ecryptfs would provide the same guarantees agains hidden file corruptions as plain btrfs (or btrfs + ecrypts) would, because of the checksumming features of btrfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is incorrect. The actual implementation of eCryptFS does *not* checksum data by default or at all. Simple demonstration:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/front /tmp/back
$ sudo mount -o key=passphrase:passwd=Test,ecryptfs_hmac,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=no,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_cipher=aes -t ecryptfs /tmp/back/ /tmp/front/
$ echo HelloWorld > /tmp/front/HelloWorld.txt
$ cat /tmp/front/HelloWorld.txt
HelloWorld
$ sudo umount /tmp/front
$ printf "deadbeaf" | dd  of=/tmp/back/HelloWorld.txt  bs=1 seek=8192 count=8 conv=notrunc
$ sudo mount -o key=passphrase:passwd=Test,ecryptfs_hmac,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=no,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_cipher=aes -t ecryptfs /tmp/back/ /tmp/front/
$ cat /tmp/front/HelloWorld.txt
<garbage>
```

Also:

```
$ ecryptfs-stat /tmp/back/HelloWorld.txt 
File version: [3]
Decrypted file size: [11]
Number of header bytes at front of file: [8192]
Metadata in the header region
Encrypted
HMAC disabled
```

eCryptfs does not give a read error or any indication that anything is wrong. Note that this is even with the `ecryptfs_hmac` option, which is supposed to enabled checksumming, but apparently doesn't. The actual source code of ecryptfs does contain HMAC code, so I am not sure why that isn't working. Quick Google search indicates that HMAC code might be incomplete. Haven't yet looked deeper into it.

Comment: Confirmed this is so on my machine too (openSUSE 13.2). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***eCryptFS*** does checksum data. There's [a paper that describes how eCryptFS works](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/eCryptfs/ecryptfs.pdf). One of the things eCryptFS does is protect against tampering of the file by adversaries, and to do that it computes a HMAC and stores it with the encrypted file. As a bonus, this obviously also protects against accidental "tampering," such as by cosmic rays, electronic noise, or simple wear-and-tear (collectively described by **bit rot**).

However, **btrfs** does one additional thing that I'm sure **eCryptFS** does not do: mirroring/replication and parity. With mirroring (RAID1) or parity (RAID5 or RAID6), btrfs is able to automatically find a good copy of a piece of file should it detect corruption with the piece currently being read. Ars Technica has a [very good article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/bitrot-and-atomic-cows-inside-next-gen-filesystems/) on corruption and how to best utilize the feature of btrfs or ZFS to keep data safe.

If you go with **ext4 and eCryptFS**, at best you would only know that something was corrupt or tampered with, but you'd have to manually intervene to deal with the problem. I would recommend sticking with **btrfs and eCryptFS**, which provides both checksumming (as long as you do not disable copy-on-write) and can also maintain redundant copies of data (using RAID1, RAID5, RAID6, or RAID10).